# Is MySQL more efficient in query optimization and general efficiency than Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I find that Apache spark is much slower then a MySQL server for the same query and the same table query on a spark data frame.

So where would be spark more efficient then MySQL?

Note : tried on a table with 1 million rows all of 10 columns of type text.

The size of table in json is about 10GB

Using a standalone pyspark notebook with Xeon 16 core and 64gb RAM and on same server MySql

In general I would like to know guidelines on when to use SPARK vs SQL server in terms of the size of target data to get real snappy results from analytic queries.

Comment: Did you try it with a terabyte of data in your MySQL table?

Comment: You mentioned RDD, but I hope you are aware that there won't be any substantial optimization done unless you use a DataSet or DataFrame.

Comment: There are entirely too many variables that could at play here.

Comment: Might need to see the infrastructure specs of both. How you wrote your spark program, what's the data source (how it's stored), etc. There are, again, so many things that could cause this.

Comment: @Nick Burns updated question

Comment: @Hawknight updated question

Comment: 1 million rows is a tiny, tiny table. Try a billion, let us know how that goes.

Comment: @DavidGriffin In general I would like to know guidelines on when to use SPARK vs SQL server in terms of the size of target data to get real snappy results from analytic queries.

Comment: If the data is too big to be contained on a single instance of MySQL, for one thing. Spark is a cluster-based architecture; where it excels is in distributing large amounts of workloads across many nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so going to try and help here even though it's still very difficult to answer this without knowing more.  Assuming there is no contention for resources, there are a number of things that are going on here. If you're running on yarn and your json is stored in hdfs. It is likely split into many blocks, those blocks are then processed in different partitions. Since json doesn't split very well, you'd lose alot of parallel capabilities. Also, spark isn't meant to really have the super low latency queries like a tuned rdbms. Where you benefit from spark is on heavy data processing, large amounts of data (TB or PB). If you are looking for low latency queries you should use Impala or Hive with Tez. You should also consider changing your file format to avro, parquet or ORC.

Comment: actually I used paraquet